# multiple csv files data to single json file

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I had two csv files named mortality1 and mortality2 and i want to insert these two csv files data into a single json file...when i am inserting these data, i am unable give the two files at the same time to json file.and this is my code

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
csvfile1 = open('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/data/mortality1.csv', 'r')
csvfile2 = open('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/data/mortality2.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/data/cvstojson.json', 'w')
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile1)
df.to_json(jsonfile)
```

i want insert the 2 csv files data at the same time to the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of your csv data are having similar structure, then you can append the data frames to one another, and then convert it to a JSON.
Like

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
csvfile1 = open('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/data/mortality1.csv', 'r')
csvfile2 = open('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/data/mortality2.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/data/cvstojson.json', 'w')

# Read and append both dataframes to single one
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile1).append(pd.read_csv(csvfile2))

# Create the json representation of all rows together.
df.to_json(jsonfile, orient="records")
```

Comment: i am not having same structure for my 2 csv files..when i do this code i am getting the output like

Comment: getting null values

Comment: Then better update your question with the data - strcutre and some samples for both files.

Comment: [{"Age":0.0,"NALM":0.001728,"qx":0.0018144,"Input Parameters":null,"Value":null}  null taking for first file also

Comment: these 2 values are from second csv file,but i am getting this information for first file also

Comment: how can i update second detail for it..there a need to not change my data

Comment: When you join two csvs, its expected that, the columns not in first one will be null. If you want process your json afterwards